# Trying to abstract away typeclass, but a type variable escapes

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I have some classes and their instances. The example shows some nonsensical classes. Their exact nature is not important.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}


class Foo a where
   foo :: a -> Int
class Bar a where
   bar :: a -> String

instance Foo Int where
   foo x = x
instance Foo String where
   foo x = length x

instance Bar Int where
   bar x = show x
instance Bar String where
   bar x = x
```

OK, now I want to create some existential types that hide these classes behind some datatype façade, so I don't have to deal with constraints. (I know existential types are considered an anti-pattern, please don't explain this to me).

```
data TFoo = forall a. Foo a => TFoo a
instance Foo TFoo where
  foo (TFoo x) = foo x
data TBar = forall a. Bar a => TBar a
instance Bar TBar where
  bar (TBar x) = bar x
```

Obviously there's some boilerplate in there. I want to abstract it away.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
data Obj cls = forall o. (cls o) => Obj o
```

So instead of several existential types I have just one, parametrised by a typeclass. So far so good.

Now how do I perform operations on `Obj a`? The obvious attempt

```
op f (Obj a) = f a
```

fails because the type variable could escape.

```
existential.hs:31:18: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘o -> p1’ with actual type ‘p’
        because type variable ‘o’ would escape its scope
      This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          Obj :: forall (cls :: * -> Constraint) o. cls o => o -> Obj cls,
        in an equation for ‘call’
        at existential.hs:31:9-13
    • In the expression: f k
      In an equation for ‘call’: call f (Obj k) = f k
    • Relevant bindings include
        k :: o (bound at existential.hs:31:13)
        f :: p (bound at existential.hs:31:6)
        call :: p -> Obj cls -> p1 (bound at existential.hs:31:1)
   |
31 | call f (Obj k) = f k
   |                  ^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I kinda understand why this happens. But with real invocations like `call foo` and `call bar` the type variable wouldn't escape. Can I convince the compiler of it? Perhaps I somehow can express the type `u -> v where v does not mention u` (which really should be the type of `f`)? If not, what other ways to deal with the situation are there? I guess I could generate something with TemplateHaskell but I still cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? What is `op`?

Comment: What you're doing is possible.  There is a more detailed error somewhere in the code that you're not showing us.

Comment: @luqui this is the exact code I'm trying to compile, and this is the only error.

Comment: @dfeuer It is my attempt to explore a little object system (as in object-oriented programming) with subtyping. `op`, or rather `flip op`, would then be a method selector, like the `.` in `object . method` of a typical OOP language. I know this may not be the best way to do it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works fine; the compiler just needs some help with its type.

`Obj` hides the type of its contents, which means that `op`'s argument `f` must be polymorphic (that is, it can't scrutinise its argument). Turn on `RankNTypes`:

```hs
op :: (forall a. cls a => a -> r) -> Obj cls -> r
op f (Obj x) = f x
```

You have to give the type signature in full because GHC can't infer higher-rank types.

Existentially quantifying over a class like this is [usually not the best way](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) to design a given program.