# Can I express a subclassing constraint?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, existential-type

Still playing with existentials over constraints (just exploring this design space, I know it is considered bad by many Haskellers). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667612/trying-to-abstract-away-typeclass-but-a-type-variable-escapes) for more info.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Foo a where
   foo :: a -> Int

class Foo a => Bar a where
   bar :: a -> String

instance Foo Int where
   foo = id

instance Bar Int where
   bar = show

data Obj cls = forall o. (cls o) => Obj o

fooable = Obj @Foo $ (42 :: Int)
barable = Obj @Bar $ (42 :: Int)

doFoo :: Obj Foo -> Int
doFoo (Obj x) = foo x
```

Now I have this problem. `doFoo fooable` works, but `doFoo barable` doesn't.

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Bar’ with ‘Foo’
  Expected type: Obj Foo
    Actual type: Obj Bar
• In the first argument of ‘doFoo’, namely ‘barable’
  In the expression: doFoo barable
  In an equation for ‘it’: it = doFoo barable
```

Which is of course true. `Obj Foo` is different for `Obj Bar`.

Can I give a suitable type to `doFoo`? Basically I want a type like `Obj cls where cls is a subclass of Foo` but I cannot find a way to express it. Please bear with me, I'm new to these wild wonderful types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a quantified constraint for that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}

doFoo :: forall c . (forall a. c a => Foo a) => Obj c -> Int
doFoo (Obj x) = foo x
```

Essentially, `doFoo` takes any `Obj c`, where `c` is any type class which implies `Foo`, i.e. a type class satisfying the quantified constraint

```
forall a. c a => Foo a
```

Comment: Thanks, QuantifiedConstraints is what I've been looking for!