# Data.Typeable.cast to an existential type

Tags: haskell, types, casting, typeclass, existential-type

So this is a continuation of my object system saga ([part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667612/trying-to-abstract-away-typeclass-but-a-type-variable-escapes), [part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673111/can-i-express-a-subclassing-constraint)).

This part essentially boils to the following.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Typeable
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

data Obj (cls :: * -> Constraint) = forall o. (cls o, Typeable o) => Obj o

downcast :: Obj a -> Maybe (Obj b)
downcast (Obj x) = do
                     cx <- cast x
                     return $ Obj cx
```

The definition of `downcast` fails with this error:

```
• Could not deduce: b o0 arising from a use of ‘Obj’
  from the context: (a o, Typeable o)
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               Obj :: forall (cls :: * -> Constraint) o.
                      (cls o, Typeable o) =>
                      o -> Obj cls,
             in an equation for ‘downcast’
    at downcast.hs:12:11-15
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘Obj cx’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: return $ Obj cx
  In the expression:
    do cx <- cast x
       return $ Obj cx
• Relevant bindings include
    cx :: o0 (bound at moo.hs:13:22)
    downcast :: Obj a -> Maybe (Obj b) (bound at downcast.hs:12:1)
```

I don't quite understand why this error happens :( Can it be fixed?

Comment: You haven't established any relationship between `a` and `b`. So GHC doesn't know that one implies the other.

Comment: More concretely, GHC doesn't know how to get a `b o` dictionary from an `a o` dictionary.

Comment: And I think you're pretty doomed, unless you manually reify the class hierarchy somehow.

Comment: @dfeuer *More concretely, GHC doesn't know how to get a b o dictionary from an a o dictionary* Yeah that's what I understood. *And I think you're pretty doomed, unless you manually reify the class hierarchy somehow* I'm not entirely opposed to that. Do you know of a way to build such a reified hierarchy?

Comment: There's some crud in the `constraints` package you might find inspirational, but I don't think it's quite the right shape for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh wait.... You're trying to *downcast*. There's basically no hope there, is there?

Comment: @dfeuer well, upcast is not a problem because the compiler can get the dictionary in the up direction...

Comment: Even upcast won't work with that type! You'd need to add a (quantified) constraint, at which point you could drop the `Maybe`. There's no way in Haskell to get a collection of all the classes a type instantiates, or to check whether a particular class is in that list.

Comment: @dfeuer it does without a Maybe of course (an upcast must always succeed). I posted it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/hisc4m/modeling_object_oriented_programming_in_haskell/fwkydii/).

Comment: Of course, but that uses an extra constraint, as I indicated.

Comment: @dfeuer ah yes I see what you mean. Anyway, I'm trying to solve this by having a hand-built collection of instances for each type. Still no luck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time your Haskell is translated into GHC Core, the classes (and the attendant logic programming constructs such as impliciation) are nowhere to be seen. They are transformed by the compiler into *dictionary passing* code — each `instance` becomes a record (a regular value) and each method becomes a member of that record. (For more specifics, see [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47535065/1523776).)

So a constructor which packages up a constraint,

```hs
data Obj c where  -- I'm using GADT syntax
    Obj :: c a => a -> Obj c
```

is really represented at runtime by a regular product type,

```hs
data Obj c where
    Obj :: c a -> a -> Obj c
```

where the `c a` field is the runtime method dictionary representing the `c a` instance.

To downcast an `Obj c` to an `Obj c'` at runtime, even if you had a way to test that the concrete `a` was an instance of both `c` and `c'`, you'd still have to somehow synthesise a dictionary for `c'`. Since `c'` will generally contain more methods than `c`, this amounts to asking the computer to write a program for you.

---

[As David mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699440/data-typeable-cast-to-an-existential-type/62705606#comment110880055_62699440), I think your best bet would be to build knowledge about your specific class hierarchy into your runtime system under a closed-world assumption. If you have an oracle which can look up an instance's actual runtime [dictionary](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.12/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict),

```hs
oracle :: MonadRuntime m => TypeRep a -> TypeRep c -> m (Maybe (Dict (c a)))
```

then you can write `cast` (with some uncomfortable type wrangling):

```hs
data Obj c where
    Obj :: c a => TypeRep a -> a -> Obj c

cast :: forall c c' m. (MonadRuntime m, Typeable c') => Obj c -> m (Maybe (Obj c'))
cast (Obj tr x) = do
    mdict <- oracle tr (typeRep @c')
    case mdict of
        Just Dict -> return (Just (Obj tr x))
        Nothing -> return Nothing
```

Note that this `cast` actually lets you (attempt to) change your object's interface to *any* other interface, not just those which are derived from the object's static type. (In C# you can do this by upcasting to `object` and then downcasting.) You can prevent this by requiring an [entailment](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.12/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t::-45-) in `cast`'s context:

```hs
cast :: forall c c' m. (MonadRuntime m, Typeable c', Class c c') => Obj c -> m (Maybe (Obj c'))
```

(Of course, that entailment would not actually be used at runtime.)

---

The challenge is to implement `oracle`! I think it’s going to be one of those challenges which is *not fun* so I'll just give you a pointer or two.

Your `Runtime` monad will probably be some sort of `Reader` with a lookup table mapping (the `TypeRep`s of) `a`s and `c`s to dictionaries. The `a`s and `c`s will need to be existentially quantified in order to store them in a heterogeneous list.

```hs
data TableEntry where
    TableEntry :: c a => TypeRep c -> TypeRep a -> TableEntry

type MonadRuntime = MonadReader [TableEntry]
```

Then `oracle` will need to look up the `TableEntry` matching the class/type pair, then open the existential, establish the type equality by taking apart the `typeRep`s, and return `Just Dict`. (This part in particular sounds like a nightmare to code up.)

Before you run your `MonadRuntime` program you'll need to construct the `Table` containing all of the instances your program cares about.

```hs
table = [
    TableEntry (typeRep @Ord) (typeRep @Int),
    TableEntry (typeRep @Eq) (typeRep @Bool)
    ]
```

---

All in all I don’t see how it could possibly be worth the headache. Type classes are fundamentally unlike OO classes (and they're not even that much like OO interfaces), so it's really not surprising that it's hard to use them to model OO classes.

Comment: I am fine with providing the dictionary manually. Say, each type that wants to be upcasted needs to be an instance of `class Castable`, with a method that provides a list of dictionaries in some form. `downcast` then would find and return `Just` the right dictionary, or `Nothing` if there's no match. I's struggling with giving this list a suitable type.

Comment: Wow that's some advanced sorcery, not sure I'm up to the task...